# Apache Spark read file as a stream from HDFS

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs

How can I read file as a stream from hdfs using Apache Spark Java?
I don't want to read whole file, I want to have file stream in order to stop reading file when some condition is met, how can I do it with Apache Spark?

Comment: Chck this :: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/HdfsWordCount.scala

Comment: This example isn't related to my question.

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to achieve? Why do you need it as a stream (as opposed to simply reading it as an RDD/Dataframe)? Are you asking how to have spark streaming read the content of an HDFS directory and stop when it is done (instead of waiting for the next time period)? Also are you talking about DStream or structured streaming?

Comment: The thing is, what will happen with Parquet file for example when you try to partially read it? What I want to say is: does it make sense (for Hadoop devs) making such functionality when the filesystem supports proprietary file formats which cannot be decoded until fully downloaded? But it is just a thought.

Comment: Assaf Mendelson, I want to read file byte by byte and stop reading it after some condition met, e.g. some symbol is found... Is it possible, or NameNode always will look for all file blocks?

Comment: In general this is not how spark works. Spark would read the file line by line (or block by block for binary files). The blocks would be distributed between different tasks and then combined. If you explain better your use case there may be a way to rephrase the question in a way which is more suitable for spark

Comment: Assaf Mendelson, I want to read file line by line and stop file reading if line contains e.g. word "stop" . Is it possible ? How productive it will be?

Comment: The problem would be that if the reading is done in multiple partitions then how would you know to stop just in one? You can create a custom reader which would read in one partition and stop when it reaches stop and then do some processing further down the line by doing a repartitioning and therefore get parallelism. You can make it "streaming" by starting to process after some data arrives (by creating a custom streaming source) or simply do a batch processing.

Comment: If you just want to process a file from the beginning to the end, why do you need to use Spark? Just using the HDFS APIs to open a file and you can stop reading at your will.

Answer (score 1):

You can use streaming HDFS file using ssc method

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(batchTime))

val dStream = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](
        streamDirectory, **(x: Path)** => true, newFilesOnly = false)

Using above api 
   param filter Function to filter paths to process.

If your condition is not with file path/name and based on data, then you need to stop streaming context if condition satisfy.

For this you need to use thread implementation,
 1) In one thread you need to keep checking for streaming context is stopped and  if ssc stopped then notify other thread to wait and create new streaming context.

2) In second thread , you need to check for condition and if condition satisfy then stop streaming context.

Please let me know if you need to explanation.

Comment: The problem that I have e.g two thound of files and I want to read only N lines from each (from few to billions). Your solution will be to much expensive.